# Segments on a closed convex plane polyline

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Is it true that there does not exist a closed convex plane polyline containing an infinite number of segments, belonging to distinct lines each?

**Edit:** Replaced broken line with a polyline, since this seems to be a more common term in literature.

Comment: If "containing" means "in that part of the plane interior to the polyline", then you can take a point $A$ inside the polyline and join it with all the points on the polyline: you'll get an infinite number of segments contained in the polyline.

Comment: a polyline "contains" a segment iff all the points of the segment belong to the line.

Comment: I see. And what is your definition of polyline?

Comment: Let us say a polyline is a curve specified by a (possibly infinite) sequence of points A1, A2, ... called its vertices. The curve itself consists of the line segments connecting the consecutive vertices. (A similar definition is given in Wikipedia, but the sequence is finite there.)

Comment: If you allow for an infinite number of vertices, then I don't see how the statement in your question could be true.